# ambiguous implicit conversion

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I'm working on a project often using 3d vector length comparison.
For this reason I made a sqrt class which implements comparison operators to compare squared values and not have to calculate a square root for no reason:

```
    template<typename source_type, typename result_type = source_type>
    struct square_root_functor : std::unary_function<source_type, result_type>
    {
        const result_type operator() (const source_type& val) const 
        { 
            return static_cast<result_type>( std::sqrt( val ) );
        }
    };

    template<typename source_type, typename result_type = source_type, typename sqrt_func = square_root_functor<source_type, result_type> >
    class square_root_proxy
    {
    public:
        explicit square_root_proxy( const source_type& value )
            : squared_value( value )
        {}

        //other operators omitted for concision

        bool operator<( const source_type& rhs )
        {
            return squared_value > rhs * rhs;
        }

        operator result_type()
        {
            return sqrt( squared_value );
        }

    private:
        const source_type& squared_value;
        sqrt_func sqrt;
    };
```

This works in most case but I found a case were I get an ambiguity the compiler can't resolve.

```
square_root_proxy<int> S = square_root_proxy<int>(9);
unsigned int I = 4;
bool B = S < I;  //AMBIGUOUS
```

The last call is ambiguous since `S` can be cast to `int` and then use `operator<(int, unsigned int)`.

Or `I` can be cast to `int` and then call `square_root_proxy<int>::operator<(int)`.

Of course, explicitly casting resolves the ambiguity but is much less convenient for the user.

Is it possible to add a priority between these two techniques so `square_root_proxy<int>::operator<(int)` has precedence?

Thanks

Details:

toolchain : Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727 for x86

actual error

```
1>main.cpp(138): error C2666: 'square_root_proxy<source_type>::operator <' : 2 overloads have similar conversions
1>          with
1>          [
1>              source_type=int
1>          ]
1>          main.cpp(114): could be 'bool square_root_proxy<source_type>::operator <(const source_type &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              source_type=int
1>          ]
1>          or       'built-in C++ operator<(int, unsigned int)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(square_root_proxy<source_type>, unsigned int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              source_type=int
1>          ]
```

Comment: If you check [`std::sqrt()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt)'s documentation, you'll see that any of the possible choices might be deduced from an `int`. Thus it's ambiguous for the compiler which one to use.

Comment: Instead of having an implicit casting operator, can you define the `operator<` or `operator>` to be a friend of the class, and have two definitions for each, one with the square class being first argument and another being the second argument?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't see the ambiguity since the std::sqrt is defined inside the operator and at `squared_value` has the type explicitly defined as the type parameter...

Comment: An [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of this would sure be nice. There is no `square_root_functor` and for whatever reason the only logical comparative operator you chose *not* to omit "for concision" is not the one suspected of invoke.

Comment: @triple_r after testing, implementing the friend class does not help resolve the ambiguity. Also I'm not sure if this was clear in the original post but the implicit casting operator is actually use so `int i = square_root_proxy<int>(9);` will work properly.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry about that, it should work now

Comment: @tiridactil thanks. time to post your toolchain.[ideone has no complaints](http://ideone.com/ZEordS), nor does my local clang 3.5. [Coliru (g++) is nearly the same](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bc1f68b141b473b), only bitching about the signed-unsigned comparison.

Comment: @WhozCraig ok I posted the toolchain, error and realized I did a major error in the code I posted, I omitted the wrong operator... sorry about that